# Can Oracle 21c PDBs reside on a NAS or external USB drive?

Tags: oracle, nas, pluggable-database

Is it possible to have an Oracle 21c program and container database (CDB) running on a server and have it run pluggable databases (PDBs) whose data files are on a NAS, external USB or other source that's accessible from the server?

I'd like to build a PDB that's several TB larger than my server's internal file storage, yet use my server's CPU/RAM to run the main Oracle programs that load data to my PDBs.  I have some 16 TB external drives connected to my network and was hoping to put my big data there.

I can run Oracle 21c on Windows or Linux...in case that makes a difference.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/supported-storage-options-for-oracle-database.html#GUID-120C3995-F827-4D01-B955-CB1BD0457AF7

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but a common cause of performance issues for a database is not the speed of the server, or the speed of the disk, but the speed of the pipe between the two.

If you opt for NAS, check out the Direct NFS features in Oracle, which reduce the impact of the various layers in the stack that NFS uses to provide IO services. It can yield good benefits.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look into that.  Though, in my case, it's just for a big data one-time data load that I'll eventually push to the cloud when I'm ready to go operational...so this may work for me.  I'll look into the Direct NFS feature